# Size of a formbean inside jsp Struts1

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, struts-1

I'm using Struts 1.xx and i want to get the size of bean in jsp.
So How to find a size of a list inside jsp.

Comment: What does size mean here? In bytes? or number of index?

Comment: I'm creating list grid by iterating the bean. So i want to know the number of raw in first. because at last i want to inactivate last raw. for that i need to get the raw size first. the number of raw may variey

Answer (score 0):

Is this a List interface ? It does not follow the javabeans convention, so I don't think that you can get the size of the list. A quick way would be to use a scriptlet `<%= mylist.size() %>`